# ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC : how to save MultiLine TextBox Text (Value) to database as new records for each new line

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

As the title says, I am wondering how I would go about parsing out multiple lines of text from a single TextBox, but submit each of those values individually to my database.

The users have a display where they enter in a barcode that represents a physical location at the facility, and they can put multiple plants in that location. So instead of having them submit a new form for every single plant, I figured this would be an easier way to do so.

However, I'm struggling to understand HOW to make this happen in my controller on the `HttpPost` event for `Create();`

The info that gets passed is: `ID, UserId, PlantId, Barcode, Date`, and `Time`. The `ID` (auto updated) and `PlantId` would be the only things that change. The Barcode, Date and Time should be the same value. I have removed all my failed attempts in my examples here so you can see how it works WITHOUT what I'm wanting to do.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,PlantId,Barcode,UserId,Date,Time")] VegLocationModel vegLocationModel)
{
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
            _context.Add(vegLocationModel);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Create));
       }

       return View(vegLocationModel);
}
```

View:

```
@model tester.Models.VegLocationModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    var userName = "TEST";
    var currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date.Month.ToString() + "/" + DateTime.Now.Date.Day.ToString() + "/" + DateTime.Now.Date.Year.ToString();
    var currentTime = string.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss tt}", DateTime.Now);
    Html.Hidden("UserId");
    Html.Hidden("Date");
    Html.Hidden("Time");
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>VegLocationModel</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Barcode" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Barcode" class="form-control" style="min-width:100%"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="Barcode" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PlantId" class="control-label"></label>
                <textarea asp-for="PlantId" class="form-control" rows="10" cols="50">
                </textarea>
                <span asp-validation-for="PlantId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="UserId" type="hidden" value="@userName" asp-for="UserId" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="UserId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="Date" type="hidden" value="@currentDate" asp-for="Date" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Date" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="Time" type="hidden" value="@currentTime" asp-for="Time" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Time" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the value of your textarea posted to Action "Create" is in type of string not int,so you couldn't bind it with VegLocationModel
you could try as below:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(SomeTest someTest,string plantid)
        {
            List<int> plantids = plantid.Split("\r\n").Select(m=>Convert.ToInt32(m)).ToList();
            return Ok();
        }
```

the result:
[image]

try as below to update your database:

```
 public  async Task<IActionResult> Create(SomeTest someTest)
    {
        List<string> plantids = someTest.PlantId.Split("\r\n").ToList();
        var soemtestlist = new List<SomeTest>();
        
        foreach (var id in plantids)
        {
            soemtestlist.Add(
                new SomeTest(){ 
                    Barcode= someTest.Barcode,                        
                    Time= someTest.Time,
                    UserId= someTest.UserId,
                    PlantId = id
                });
        }
        
      
        _context.SomeTest.AddRange(soemtestlist);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok();
    }
```

The Result：
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response! The problem with this one, is the PlantId ARE stored as strings. The Id's we use for plants are very long. Similar to a format like this, 1A40C000000345B000006285. So wouldn't the List be like,

List<string> plantids = PlantId.Split("\r\n").Select(m => Convert.ToString(m)).ToList();

My question from here is pretty much how to put all of the PlantId's into the database separately, with the same UserId, Date, and Time. But rn, I just store the UserId into the Session. Alot of things are different in ASP.NET Core 6. Sorry for the sloppy reply. Not at work atm.

Comment: could you shou your model class ,dbcontext ?

Comment: using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace tester.Models
{
    public class VegLocationModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name ="Plant Id(s)")]
        public string PlantId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Barcode { get; set; }  
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string Time { get; set; }

    }
}

Comment: using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using tester.Models;

namespace tester.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
            _options = options; 
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }

        public DbSet<VegLocationModel> VegLocations { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: I've updated my answer,please check it

Comment: I fixed the code a bit, so it will function as intended, but the issue now seems to be that I can't increment the Primary Key in the database. I now get the error, SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'VegLocations' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

https://justpaste.it/8pzrq

Comment: I've updated my answer it could work now，and in the property [Bind("Id,PlantId,Barcode,UserId,Date,Time")]delet "id" ,it will be ok

Comment: You nailed it. The exact function I was looking for and working perfectly. Thank you a TON for your help. Do you have a tip jar so I can get you a coffee? Haha

Answer (score 0):

In the multiline textbox, the new line can be separated as \r\n (works in windows) OR \n\r depending on the operating system. So, logic is simple. Just split your multiline textbox with either \n\r or \r\n and store it in separate rows in the database.